# Change the location where git looks for its dependency

Tags: git, unix, aix

I am getting this error while doing git checkout from ANT.

```
[exec] exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program git because of the following errors:
     [exec]     0509-150   Dependent module /usr/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.1) could not be loaded.
     [exec]     0509-152   Member libcrypto.so.1.0.1 is not found in archive
     [exec] Result: 255
```

I know this dependency **libcrypto.so.1.0.1** is there in /opt/freeware/lib/. But git is looking for it in /usr/lib. Do we have any way to ask git to look in /opt/freeware/lib.

Answer (score 3):

The problem may come from the fact that you are using a binary compiled on a different machine and depdencies are not stored in the same path they are stored on the original machine the binary has been compiled in.

You may want to use a tool like 'chrpath' to change path to your library (I don't know if it exists on AIX).

You also can try changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the path containing your libcrypto library.